# A question about relation of the character degrees of $ G/N $ and $ G $

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $ G $ be a finite group and $ N $ be a normal subgroup of $ G $. Let $ G/N $ have two irreducible characters of degrees  $ p_1$ and $ p_2$, where $ p_1$ and $ p_2$ are different primes. Let $ G/N $ have no irreducible character such that $ p_1p_2\mid \chi (1) $. If $ (p_1p_2, |N|)=1$, can we say that $G $ has no irreducible character $\chi $  such that $ p_1p_2\mid \chi (1) $?
I guess that this is impossible but I could not find any counterexample for it.

Comment: Could you add some motivation for your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice example. This topic is related to the structure of character degree graph of a finite group and I want to know the relations between the character degree graphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible for $G$ to have such a character. The smallest example has order $120$. Let $N = \langle k \rangle \cong C_5$. Let $G = N \rtimes S_4$ where the action of the symmetric group $S_4$ on $N$ is non-trivial but factors through the sign representation. Thus $k^{(12)} = k^{-1}$, $k^{(234)} = k$ and $\langle k, (12)\rangle$ is dihedral of order $10$. The character degrees of $G$ are $\{1,2,3,6\}$ and the character degrees of $G/N \cong S_4$ are $\{1,2,3\}$.